# How to make Jaxrs-Analyzer to generate swagger 2 definition json docs?

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-maven-plugin

When I use `Jaxrs-Analyzer Version 0.9`, it generates `swagger 1.2` json docs. How can i configure `jaxrs-analyzer` to make sure it generates `swagger 2` json definitions?

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.sebastian-daschner</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-jaxrs</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Available backends, defaults to plaintext -->
                            <!-- <backend>plaintext</backend> -->
                            <backend>swagger</backend>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Edit**

Sample swagger json doc;

```
{
  "apiVersion" : "1",
  "swaggerVersion" : "1.2",
  "basePath" : "/testwar/rest",
  "resourcePath" : "/TankSystems",
  "apis" : [ {
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using my tool!

The JAX-RS Analyzer is indeed generating Swagger Version **2.0** right now (not 1.2). Only this version is supported currently.

Are there any points where the generated Swagger JSON doesn't comply to the Swagger (aka OpenAPI) 2.0 definition?

Also see [Swagger Definition](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) and [Swagger Migration Guide](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/wiki/Swagger-1.2-to-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: For me it generates swagger 1.2 doc..I edited my question with sample json.

Comment: Are you using other plugins in your Maven build like swagger-doclet? The JAX-RS Analyzer tool had never other Swagger versions included than 2.0, so I'm sure the JSON above came from some other plugin.

Comment: You are right,  <doclet>com.carma.swagger.doclet.ServiceDoclet</doclet> caused the issue

Comment: Hi, could you please fix dependency for gradle project